# Security Question before sending form - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a random math question to check if the user is not a bot so I want to check if the user has the right number.

```
let n1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 2;
let n2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 2;
let result = n1 + n2;
```

I put this inside router.get. I got a router.post with a form and there I want the check

```
 if (req.body.SecureValue !== result) {
        // errorMessage
    }
```

but if I execute it throws

### ReferenceError: result is not defined

I tried to define the variable inside the post request and also outside every router but it doesnt work.
router.get

```
router.get('/contact', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(result);
    res.render('default/contact', {
        layout: 'layouts/default',
        n1: n1,
        n2: n2,
        SecureValue: req.body.SecureValue
    });
```

})
router.post

```
router.post('/contact/send', (req, res) => {
    // Security Request
    if (req.body.conSecureValue !== result) {
        res.redirect('/contact');
    }
// Nodemailer settings
...
})
```

Comment: How did you try to define it? We need some more code/context here. Please post actual code, not a description of what you attempted.

Comment: Are you assuming bots can't add up.?

Answer (score -1):

If you defined this inside another method then all the variables get erased from memory after the response get sent to the client. You need to define it globally and send it in both requests:

```js
let n1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 2;
let n2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 2;
let result = n1 + n2;

route.get('/path', function(req, res) {
   //use n1 and n2 here
});

route.post('/otherpath', function(req, res) {
   //use results here
});
```

Comment: If I do so it throws: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: This error is not related with what i did. It's related to how you send your response .. can you share the get and post function in the question above?

Comment: You can't use global variables for this. You'll hit an instant race condition as soon as you get two users at the same time.

Comment: @Dariun I see. You are using `req.body` in a get request which is not allowed .. body only works with post request. You may want to use `req.query` to send query params int he url.